# I need help understanding "List" Keyword Question in Python

Tags: python

I'm tearing what little hair I have out over this.  I have the following statement:

`list = []`

`list` is in an alternate color in the IDE, indicating it being a keyword.  I saw reference to as a keyword online.  However, all examples treat the position of `list` in the statement as being a simple user-assigned name (like "my_list" or something like that).  I'm trying to get rid of a bunch of unnecessary junk in the code, but if I remove the `del` statement after it, a subsequent use the name `list` crashes the program.  If I put the `del` back in, it works.  If it's an simply and assignment statement, I could expect a subsequent assignment would replace the previous one, regardless of the presence of `del`.

To complicate matters in my mind, the subsequent reference talks about `list` like an module (i.e. list().  If I try to change the name of the first reference to `list1 = []` the actual use of the structure fails as "non-iterable."

Sorry if this drones, but this doesn't make sense to me.

Continuation:
The first few statements are:

```
list = []
p = 129
for loop in range(1, math.ceil(len(files)/4) + 1):
list.append(p)
p = p + 140
```

After the loop finishes:
del list.

Later:

```
WOW_time_1 = list(fti.loc[:
'NLG Wow(takeo0ff)'].dropna()). . .
```

My expectation would be that the first statement (list = []) is defining the structure.  In that case, I would think that a user-defined name should be used, except for the fact it uses the "append" method later.  Then, after del, it's used again without any sort of declaration.  If it's a keyword that is always available, I don't get why it was declared in the first place and why I have to del it in order for the second reference to it will work.

Oh, and for the record, I'm debugging this, not writing it.  :-)

Comment: I just checked in my REPL: `list` is a **class**.

Comment: ```list``` is a keyword in python. You can initialize by using ```list()```. [src](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

Comment: Can you post your code that's causing the problem? That'd be a lot clearer than explaining it in English (but that's also nice).

Comment: Ok...python standard modules includes code that define list. By writing `list = []` you are breaking that code. That’s why it’s a keyword and should not be used.

Comment: The first few statements are:

Comment: `list` is a built-in type. It you name anything `list` it will mask the original for the used namespace. Depending on your code it can have hard to debug side-effects. So, don't name anything like the built-in names.

Comment: naming variables after built-ins is how you summon wrathful Old Gods

Comment: I fixed your code block, but there was no indentation visible. Can you edit it?

Answer (score -1):

The name `list` is being used for two different things in the code you're reading.

Lets start with the second use, since it's the more normal one. When the code does `list(...)`, it's calling the builtin type named `list`, which builds a list object and fills it with the values from the iterable argument passed to it. You've probably used this type many times, though you might not have called `list` directly too often (since you can build a list with literal syntax, e.g. `[1, 2, 3]`).

The other use of `list` earlier in the file is as a variable. This is legal to do, but it is generally considered bad code style to use the name of a builtin for your own purposes. When you make an assignment to the name of a builtin, the builtin will be shadowed in your current namespace, so you can't easily access the normal value. The code you've shown us binds an empty list object (an instance of the builtin `list` class, though created with the literal `[]`, rater than the equivalent `list()`) to the name `list`, then fills it up with various numbers.

After the variable isn't needed any more, the code calls `del list`, which removes the variable from the local namespace, ending the shadowing of the builtin type. This is likely the result of some previous debugging of this code, as shadowing the `list` builtin was probably breaking the later code. A much better fix would have been to change the upper code to use a different variable name and avoid the shadowing in the first place.

As for why `list` is always highlighted, your code editor likely knows that `list` is the name of a builtin. So it highlights the name everywhere it's used, even when it isn't actually referring to the builtin type at that particular moment. Some editors that run style-checking programs on your code may give you a warning when you shadow a builtin name.

It's maybe worth noting that `list` is not a keyword in Python. You may notice that the highlighting is different for names that *are* keywords, like `True`, `False` and `None` (which all also refer to builtin objects), but it could be the editor chooses to use the same color for all of them. It's probably more likely to use a different color for non-object keywords, like `if` and `for`. You can't assign to any of the keywords, so `True = 0`, `if = 0` and so on will give you an error.

Comment: Excellent @Blckknight !  So frustrating to try to pick up, yet another language, on the fly.  I'm getting too old for this stuff!  I appreciate the patience and pray that I have enough brain cells left to learn this.